# Full screen WP universal app

Tags: c#, windows-phone, fullscreen, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

I have small problem (so far) at developing my first universal app, when I test it on my phone, app isn't full screen, there is black line for task bar ( that's invisible ) at the top. So does anyone know how to make an app that uses full screen or how to color task bar and make it visible in windows universal app.
I know how to do both in windows 8.1 but I have no clue here.

Thanks for all help in advance and happy holidays.

[Way app look on my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0rWL.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```
ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.FullScreen;
```

For runtime switching to fullscreen there is also this method call:

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterFullScreenMode();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I think it should work for me, I was reading windows help about it. But can I just ask you, where would you put that code to work properly, do I have to add some library?

Comment: also you can mark the answer as accepeted if it has been helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

Above is StatusBar, to hide it:

```
 var statusBar = StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();
 await statusBar.HideAsync();
```